# How can I fetch Microsoft Teams Admin Center organization data in PowerBI Reports using API

Tags: azure, powerbi, microsoft-teams, analytics

I want to fetch Enterprise level Microsoft teams admin center utilization data and create reports in Power BI using an API. Can anyone please help me with the detail steps to achieve the same.

I tried to create Power BI report using CQD data but was unable to create new measures. Getting an error:

> Could not fold the expression to the data source.

If the above way does not work, I need to fetch the data using an API to create Power BI report.
Any one of the methods will help.